# Arrays and Array lists

Tags: java, arrays

I have most of my program done, but it's not working as I need it to and I've stared at it for a while and I just can't figure it out. Can someone help me notice what I am doing wrong? I'm not asking for someone to just fix it, but explain it.

> 1. Create a class called CustomerLister1 with a main method that instantiates an array of String objects called customerName.  The
>      array should have room for seven String objects.  Assign each of the
>      following Strings to sequential locations in the array beginning at
>      array index 0.
>
>    ```
>    Chris
>    Lois
>    Meg
>    Peter
>    Stewie
>    ```
>
>    Write an enhanced for loop to display the array of names.  What is displayed for the last two array elements?  Why is it that value?
>
>    Add the Strings “Meg” and “Brian” into index 3, and 4, respectively, so that the array contains the following elements:
>
>    ```
>    Chris
>    Lois
>    Meg
>    Meg
>    Brian
>    Peter
>    Stewie
>    ```
>
>    Write an enhanced for loop to display the array of names.
>
>    Write a second, traditional for loop that checks each element for the String “Meg”, if found in the array, remove it, shift the
>      remaining elements, and display the array of names.  Are both
>      instances of “Meg” removed correctly from the array?
> 2. Modify the code you wrote part #1 for a second class called CustomerLister2 so that you are using an ArrayList instead of an array
>      to store the names as String objects.
>
>    Add the five names as done previously, and then add “Brian” so that it
>      is the 4th name in the ArrayList.  Now add “Meg” into the third
>      position in the list (there will be two identical strings “Meg” in the
>      list).
>
>    Use an enhanced for loop for displaying all the String objects, as in
>      part #1 and use a traditional for loop to remove “Meg” and show the
>      revised ArrayList.  Once again, was “Meg” removed completely from the
>      list?

```
public class CustomerLister1
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   String[] customerName = new String[7];
   customerName[0] = "Chris";
   customerName[1] = "Lois";
   customerName[2] = "Meg";
   customerName[3] = "Peter";
   customerName[4] = "Stewie";

   for (int i = customerName.length-1; i > 3; i--)
    {
      customerName[i] = customerName[i - 2];
    }
     customerName[3] = "Meg";
     customerName[4] = "Brian";


   for (int m = 0; m <= customerName.length-1; m++)
    {
     if (customerName[m].equals("Meg"))
      {
       for (int j = m; j < customerName.length; j++)
        {
         if (j < customerName.length-2)
         {
         customerName[j] = customerName[j+1];
        } else { 
           customerName[j] = "";
          }
         }
         m++;
        }
        for (String element : customerName)
        {
         System.out.println(element);
        }
        }
       }
     }
```

Comment: 'Can someone help me notice what I am doing wrong?' What exactly is wrong?

Comment: You can't just thow the whole assignment and the whole code at us without explaining anything. Explain precisely what problem you're facing. Tell us what you get as output, and what you expect instead. And indent your code properly. It's unreadable as is.

Comment: Right. It prints out way too many things I'm pretty sure. I was unable to attend class when we went over arrays because of weather conditions so I'm honestly not sure if it even prints out the correct thing.

Comment: The problem statement asks you to "Write an enhanced for loop to display the array of names.".  You might want to learn what an enhanced for loop is, as you're not using one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an "enhanced" loop (I think) is a for-each loop. It looks like this in java.

```
for (String name : customerName) {
     System.out.println(name);
}
```

whereas a traditional for loop is iteration, which is what you were doing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
     System.out.println(customerName[i]);
}
```

You are printing too much output mainly because your last for loop is embedded too far. Let me increase the tab stops to make it more obvious.

```
for (int m = 0; m <= customerName.length-1; m++)
{
     if (customerName[m].equals("Meg"))
     {
           for (int j = m; j < customerName.length; j++)
           {
                 if (j < customerName.length-2)
                 {
                        customerName[j] = customerName[j+1];
                 } else { 
                        customerName[j] = "";
                 }
           }
           m++;
       }
       for (String element : customerName)
       {
            System.out.println(element);
       }
 }
```

Do you see how your last for loop is embedded into your first one? This means everytime the first for loop `for (int m = 0; m <= customerName.length-1; m++)` runs, the last for loop is ALSO going to run. Which means the entire loop runs m times.

For a mathematical explanation, `LoopA` runs n times. `LoopB` runs m times. If `LoopB` is inside of `LoopA` then `LoopB` will run a total of n * m times.

Comment: Ahhhh how did I not notice that. Thank you. But now my program only prints out the original 5 names. I think what I need it to do is something similar to what I had it doing

Comment: If the last loop is only printing the original names, than your shifting algorithm isn't correct. (which, by looking at it, it is not). I will give you a hint, you have two small bugs.

Comment: Ask yourself, "how does a for loop work, and what is the purpose of each statement inside the for?" For example, each statement between the semicolons of the for statement, what do they mean?

Comment: You also have a conceptual bug that is actually fairly significant. You might want to consider "running" the loop on paper, looking at every value, seeing what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with many outputs is obvious as you have your printing loop inside your "enhanced" loop, whatever that means.

Other than that you should use <= in your innermost loop as you also want to move the very last element.